# volley post arrayrequest not working

Tags: java, php, arrays, http-post, android-volley

I tried to create code to get all users from my server except me.

It is not jumping to the @overwrite response.

I hope sombody can help me.

I was looking now for days why it's not working

XD didnt found the prob.

My php code:

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "userID", "password", "database");

    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $passwort = $_POST["passwort"];

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE name = ? AND passwort = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $name, $passwort);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $userID, $name, $vorname, $nachname, $passwort);

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = false;  

    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
        $response["success"] = true;  
        $response["name"] = $name;
        $response["vorname"] = $vorname;
        $response["nachname"] = $nachname;
        $response["passwort"] = $passwort;
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

In JAVA they all come together:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.example.android.app.Data.LoginRequest;
import com.example.android.app.Data.RegistryRequest;
import com.example.android.app.Data.UserlistRequest;
import com.example.android.app.Tools.User;
import com.example.android.app.Tools.UserAdapter;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;

public class listeAndererActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String Tag="lsiteanderer";
    private ArrayList<User> userListe = new ArrayList<>();
    private UserAdapter useradapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_liste_anderer);
        String ownname="juli";

        /////VERSION 2///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        Response.Listener<JSONArray> responseListenerJSONArray=new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                try {
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject (i);
                        User user = new User (obj.getString ("name"),obj.getInt("user_id"));

                        Log.v(Tag, "name in der for schlife ist"+user.getName());
                        userListe.add(user);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        useradapter=new UserAdapter(this, userListe);

        UserlistRequest userlistRequest =  new UserlistRequest(ownname, responseListenerJSONArray);
        RequestQueue queue= Volley.newRequestQueue(listeAndererActivity.this);
        queue.add(userlistRequest);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.AndererListe);

        listView.setAdapter(useradapter);
    }
}
```

My Reqest Class:

```
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import org.json.JSONArray;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by Juli on 17.12.2017.
 */

public class UserlistRequest extends JsonArrayRequest {

    private static final String userlistRequestUrl="https://unityentertainment.000webhostapp.com/OtherUser.php";
    private Map<String,String> params;


    public  UserlistRequest(String name, Response.Listener<JSONArray> listener){
        super(Request.Method.POST, userlistRequestUrl, listener, null);

        params= new HashMap<>();
        params.put("name", name);
    }

   // public UserlistRequest(String ownname, Listener<JSONArray> responseListenerJSONArray) {
     //   super();
   // }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }
}
```

My Data Class:

```
public class User {
    private String name;
    private int user_id;

    public User(String name, int user_id){
        this.name=name;
        this.user_id=user_id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }
}
```

My Adapter:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.example.android.app.R;
import com.example.android.app.ListeAndererActivity;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class UserAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> {
    public UserAdapter(ListeAndererActivity activity, ArrayList<User> userArrayList) {
        super((Context) activity, 0 ,userArrayList);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Check if the existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if(listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.itemlist_user, parent, false);
        }

        // Get the {@link AndroidFlavor} object located at this position in the list
        User currentAndroidFlavor = getItem(position);

        // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID version_name
        TextView nameTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.itemlistUser_TextView);
        // Get the version name from the current AndroidFlavor object and
        // set this text on the name TextView
        nameTextView.setText(currentAndroidFlavor.getName());

        return listItemView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should track your request and response and see where it stops. Use somthing like postman or some firefox/chrome plugin to test the back end php rest API part of your code  and narrow down the possibilities and also monitor the testing device log by printing values and look where your code is stopping or behave different than intended.

Comment: thanks for the answer but I couldn't figure out how postman works

Comment: use this firefox plugin https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/restclient/   its simpler than postman

Comment: did you saw me debug answer already maybe you get smarter out of it;-)

Comment: @Jusi you mean his php back end is ok ? maybe he has a db error as well . why not show the OP and us how to debug so we can get really smarter !

Answer (score 0):

from my opinion you should first use api testing softwares like [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/).
[postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) is great for that.
also this worked for me

```
$stmt=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM search WHERE designation LIKE ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$a);
    $stmt->execute();
    $d=$stmt->get_result();
    while($b=$d->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $result[]=$b;
}
//you could then do something like this
$response['test']=$result;
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: i meen how can i use the post method in the jsonarray request in the volley libary.  So it get dilivert to my php script. cause just the jsonstring request surports the post method  there you can use:
 @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }

Comment: in the volley request define it is a post request in the string request like StringRequest str= new StringRequest (Request.Method.POST

Comment: Look answer below

Answer (score 0):

I did like below:

```
public class UserlistRequest extends JsonArrayRequest {

    private static final String userlistRequestUrl="https://unityentertainment.000webhostapp.com/OtherUser.php";
    private Map<String,String> params;

    public UserlistRequest(String name, Response.Listener<JSONArray> listener) {
        super(Method.POST, userlistRequestUrl, (String) null, listener, null);



    // public  UserlistRequest(String name, Response.Listener<JSONArray> listener){
     //   super(Request.Method.POST, userlistRequestUrl, listener, null);


    params= new HashMap<>();
        params.put("name", name);
        params.put("name", name);

}

   // public UserlistRequest(String ownname, Listener<JSONArray> responseListenerJSONArray) {
     //   super();
   // }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't use the `getparams`